# Is it possible to join regions of an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image with some regions that I would like to join, would this be possible?

The image is the following:

[image]

I'm using regionprops to count that regions as well, and I want that the result of this image is 2 regions instead of 4 that actually are, more or less like that:

[image]

(this image is an example, in order to explain it better).

In fact, I want to join the regions that are near each other.

Would this be possible? How?

Comment: 1. how do you define the regions? 2. How do you want to join them? 3. What does the code look like / what format is your image data in? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make some improvements to this post so it can be more easily answered!

Comment: Can you show a pictorial demonstration of how image looks after joining?

Comment: How do you define "near each other"? Is it some fixed distance?

Comment: You are completely right, I was not very specific. What I needed was what Alex Miller suggested on his answer. Thanks to all for answering!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first convolve

(`conv2`  -- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

the original image with a 2D Gaussian in order to smooth the image.  In doing so, the edges of the *regions* will be broadened and run into one another -- effectively making multiple regions that are close together bleed into one region.  You will have to play with the 2D Gaussian by varying your sigma in order to achieve the desired smoothness.

Once the image is filtered/smoothed, you can use your original algorithm within `regionprops` to count the number or regions.

Let me know if that helps or if I am being unclear.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks @AlexMiller